# What is written about "Rakshas Vivah " in various scriptures?

Tags: marriage

Rakshas Vivah is considered as valid form of Marriage for Kshatriyas .
What is written about Rakshas Vivah in various scriptures ?

Comment: Rakshas Vivah is a condemned form of marriage.